# Vite Reload Loop

Tags: reactjs, docker, vite, caddy

I am trying to finish a migration away from Parcel and into Vite. We use caddy to reverse proxy a custom domain locally through a Docker container. The issue I'm having is that when I load the client in browser it continuously refreshes, the console saying that vite is connecting, then "server connection lost, polling for restart" in a loop.

Here is the vite.config.json:

```
// @ts-ignore
import tailwindcss from "@tailwindcss/jit";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
// import reactRefresh from "@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh";
// @ts-ignore
import dotenv from "dotenv";
// import postcssImport from "postcss-import";
import presetEnv from "postcss-preset-env";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

// export default (() => {
// Object.assign(process.env, loadEnv("", ".."));
// dotenv.config({ path: "../.env" });
// now you can access config with process.env.{configName}

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    // hmr: false,
    port: 1234,
  },
  plugins: [react()],
  css: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [
        tailwindcss,
        presetEnv({ stage: 1 }),
      ],
    },
  },
});
// });
```

I've pull the container logs and don't see any crashes reported. I've tried toying with the config but to no real effect.

Comment: I'm trying to get HMR working via Docker and I can see the same problem you are having. It is not able to reach the HMR host and reloads the page. If you uncomment your `hmr` line there then you'll see it stops trying to do HMR and therefore stops failing and doesn't restart as a consequence (but you don't get HMR either). In theory if you fix the HMR access issue then you should solve it and retain HMR. Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue and using the `clientPort` option in the the config solved it form me.

I'm also using Caddy inside Docker and here's my config:

```
:80 {
    reverse_proxy /api/* back:3000
    reverse_proxy /graphql back:3000
    reverse_proxy front:8080
}
```

I use it as a reverse proxy and here "front" makes reference to my Vue app served by Vite in development mode.

By adding this in my *vite.config.ts* it fixed the problem.

```
 server: {
    port: 8080,
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    hmr: {
      clientPort: 80,
    },
  },
```

[Link to vite doc - server.hmr config](https://vitejs.dev/config/#server-hmr)

Not sure if that's the correct solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: I only added the hmr clientPort like HamzStramGram did, and it solved my problem. i.e. server:{hmr:{clientPort:80,},}, Other information is redundant to me and makes my server not reachable. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am also in the process of migrating a Vue app to Vite. Therefore I changed the `ports` in `docker-compose.yml` from the standard-Vue `8080->8080` to Vite's `3000->8080` (to keep the outward-facing port the same).

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
        ...
        ports:
        - 8080:3000
```

However, Vite would not know about this port remapping. Thus I needed to add `clientPort: 8080` (my actually exposed port) to `vite.config.js`:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  ...
  server: {
    hmr: {
      clientPort: 8080,
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem using nginx with ssl. It was trying on port 80 with `ws` instead of `wss`. Your details will be different, but I looked at the logs to see what nginx was doing, then looked in the browser to see what it was trying to do. This is my (partial) `vite.config.js`:

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    // hot module reload for dev server
    hmr: {
      host: 'yourhost',
      protocol: 'wss',
      clientPort: 443
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: HamzStramGram's answer solved my problem for http, but this one solved both http and https reload loop issue for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I Had similar issue, reverse proxy with nginx. The problem fixed by:

Add hmr path to *vite.config.js*

```
server: {
  port: 3000,
  hmr: {
    path: 'ws',
  },
},
```

And add nginx config for reversing *ws* path

```
location / {...}
# new config start
location /ws {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```