# Failed to connect to websocket

Tags: websocket, vite, laravel-9, laragon

I need your help...I've basically exhausted all the link proposed by Google :D
And nothing help me pinpoint the problem...hence the fix.

If I use the command: npm run dev, I have the following error in the browser console (the page is nonetheless displayed...it just take longer)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nvP5.png)

The error does not appear with the: npm run build.

I`m using the following .env config

```
APP_NAME=App
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=*censored*
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://app.dev
```

and .vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

Laragon is launched with following environment
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dYx4.png)

Thank you !!
LN

I saw that it might be due to SSL and that I might need to install a self-serving certificate module...but I did not see clear instructions so for now I have not try this piste

Answer (score 21):

I realize this question is from November, but if you or other visitors from Google are having this issue, my solution was to update my `vite.config.js`:

```js
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ["resources/css/app.css", "resources/js/app.js"],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    server: {
        hmr: {
            host: "localhost",
            protocol: "ws",
        },
    },
});
```

I'm using `valet secure` to host my test site. Falling-back to `ws` instead of `wss`, and specifying `localhost` (Firefox and other browsers permit CORS to this location) fixed live reload, and things are working normally again.

Comment: Hello @stephancasas,,,a big thanks ! I have no idea why, nor how. I tested this kind of config and it was not working...I tested it here following your reply...and it worked. =_= Thanks !

Comment: If, in your earlier config, you used `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`, that may have been part of the problem. IIRC, browsers permit `localhost` for receiving mixed content security, but will not permit `127.0.0.1`. Either way, I'm glad it's working for you!

Comment: this one solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70882663/vite-reload-loop

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me when I hosted it. My solution was to add :

```
server: {
    hmr: {
        host: 'localhost'
    }
}
```

To your vite.config.js file. So yours will be :

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

The references can be found [here](https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/issues/127#issuecomment-1287528265) and [here](https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/pull/42)

Comment: Thank you @Miretazam ! I think I tried but I'll check again as soon as I have access to my PC and let you know. It is appreciated :)

Comment: I can´t figure out how to make it work yet :/ ... I still got the error or another error by using this option.