# client.ts:48 [vite] failed to connect to websocket. - AspNet backend and Reack on frontend

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

First, sorry for any misspeling, english is not my first language.

Don't know if someone can help me on this.

I have an AspNet app for my backend, just for jwt token generation. It works just fine.

Then i have a react whith typescript with vite on the frontend.

**Created an SSL to teste HTTPS requests, then happens this error:
client.ts:48 [vite] failed to connect to websocket.
your current setup:
(browser) localhost:5005/ <--[HTTP]--> localhost:5005/ (server)
(browser) localhost:5005/ <--[WebSocket (failing)]--> localhost:5005/ (server)
Check out your Vite / network configuration and https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-hmr .**

Tried the solution of this topic
**[Failed to connect to websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74465346/failed-to-connect-to-websocket)**

Checked about dozens of topics, but nothing helped, even chatGpt couldnt help, hehe.

This is my vite.config.ts.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 5005,
    https: {
      key: './ssl/localhost.key',
      cert: './ssl/localhost.crt'
    },
    strictPort: true,
    hmr: {
      //clientPort: 5005, //GET http://localhost:5005/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
      //clientPort: 5010, //port to nowhere, GET http://localhost:5010/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
      //clientPort: 5001, //port to my api http link, goes on an infinite loop
      host: "localhost",
      protocol: "ws"
  },
  },
});
```

Whant to make a communication whet HTTPS with my front and back end to work without errors.

But after the first request with axios, any refresh on the page generates the error.

This does not occur on firefox.